# Virtual field in 'fields' find condition - Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a Student model with a virtual field:

```
    var $virtualFields = array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT(Student.fname, " ", Student.lname)'
);
```

I am doing a find operation to fetch specific fields using 'fields':

```
$this->Student->find('all', array('fields' => array('Student.fname','Student.lname')));
```

For some reason, the virtual field is not being created after finding the records. I tried adding `Student.full_name` but of course it gives an `unknown column` error in mysql.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't specify in fields a virtual field you need to call it without the fields option so it bring it with the results... you may wanna read the [examples in the cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/virtual-fields.html)

calling all fields is one option another one is to call the field in the fields option, something like this

```
$this->Student->find('all', array('fields' => array(
    $this->student->virtualFields['full_name'].'AS Student__full_name',
    'Student.fname','Student.lname')
));
```

Answer (score 1):

what about placing a method in your app_model.php like so:

```
/**
 * combine virtual fields with fields values of find()
 * USAGE:
 * $this->Model->find('all', array('fields' => $this->Model->virtualFields('full_name')));
 * @param array $virtualFields to include
 */
public function virtualFields($fields = array()) {
    $res = array();
    foreach ((array)$fields as $field) {
        //TODO: if key numeric => value sql!
        //TODO: allow combined/other models via Model.field syntax
        $sql = $this->virtualFields[$field];
        $res[] = $sql.' AS '.$this->alias.'__'.$field;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array('fields' => $this->Model->virtualFields('full_name')))
```

));

or so:

```
$fields = $this->Model->virtualFields('full_name');
$fields = am($fields, 'status', 'created');
$this->Model->find('all', array('fields' => $fields));
```

));

Comment: I enhanced it a little bit and added some more functionality - in case you're interested: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/13/working-with-virtual-fields-in-cake1-3/

Answer (score 1):

On the CookBook:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

It says that you can use it like:

Model:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
'name' => 'CONCAT(User.first_name, " ", User.last_name)');
```

Controller or View:

```
$results = $this->User->find('first');
```

Result:

```
array(
    [User] 
        [first_name] => 'Mark',
        [last_name] => 'Story',
        [name] => 'Mark Story',
        //more fields.
    )
```

So you can use it just like this:

```
$this->set('list_fields', $this->User->find('list', 
array('fields' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'name'), 
'recursive' => -1, 'condition' => ...)));
```